# Collation - What is the purpose of this in MySQL.

Tags: mysql

I am not sure of what is this and what is the difference.  There are multiple values seen at the time of table creation

Thanks in advance

Comment: Check this for more details and effect [charset-collation-effect](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-collation-effect.html)

Answer (score 0):

A **collation** is a set of rules for comparing characters in a character set.

See [Character Sets and Collations in General](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html)